# How to improve the donut chart in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, donut-chart

And I am trying to do a chart like this one

[image: [enter image description here][2],]

... but instead of a pie chart I wanna do a Donut chart.

However I can't figure out how to do that. This is my chart until now:

[image]

**My data:**

```
          Quantidade_de_ativos_por_setor = data.frame(
          Setor = c("Outros","Lajes corporativas", "Logística", "Shoppings", "Híbridos", "Hotel", "Residencial", "Hospital", "Títulos e Val Mob"),
          Ativos_por_setor = c(198, 155, 111, 92, 83, 28, 4, 3, 1),
          Porcentagem_por_Setor = c(29.33, 22.96, 16.44, 13.63,12.30, 4.15, 0.59, 0.44, 0.15))
```

**My code:**

```
    Quantidade_de_ativos_por_setor <- FIIS %>%
    group_by(Setor)%>%
    summarize(Ativos_por_setor = sum(Quantidade_de_Ativos))%>%
    mutate(Porcentagem_por_Setor = (Ativos_por_setor/sum(Ativos_por_setor))*100)%>%
    arrange(desc(Ativos_por_setor))


Quantidade_de_ativos_por_setor$Porcentagem_por_Setor <- round(Quantidade_de_ativos_por_setor$Porcentagem_por_Setor, digit=2)

Hsize<- 1.5

  ggplot(Quantidade_de_ativos_por_setor, aes(x = Hsize, y = Ativos_por_setor, fill = Setor)) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("n = ", Ativos_por_setor, ", \n", Porcentagem_por_Setor, "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5 )) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  xlim(c(0.1, Hsize + 0.5)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank())
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add your data like a code chunk?

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Comment: Have you seen [ggpubr](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggdonutchart.html), maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

It uses a pipe and `mutate` to compute

- More than the maximum 8 colors allowed by the palette `"Dark"`;
- coordinates for `geom_text` and `geom_text_repel`;
- the labels to be displayed, inside the donut they have 3 lines of text, outside only one line.

The code is inspired in [this R Graph Gallery post](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/128-ring-or-donut-plot.html) and on [this R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/09/how-to-expand-color-palette-with-ggplot-and-rcolorbrewer/).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

colorcount <- nrow(Quantidade_de_ativos_por_setor)
getPalette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(colorcount, "Dark2"))

Quantidade_de_ativos_por_setor %>%
  mutate(fraction = Porcentagem_por_Setor/sum(Porcentagem_por_Setor),
         ymax = cumsum(fraction),
         ymin = c(0, head(ymax, n = -1)),
         xlabel = ifelse(fraction > 0.04, 3.5, NA_real_),
         xlabel_repel = ifelse(fraction < 0.04, 4.25, NA_real_),
         ylabel = (ymax + ymin) / 2,
         label = ifelse(fraction > 0.04, 
                        paste(Setor, "\n n =", Ativos_por_setor, "\n", percent(fraction)),
                        paste0(Setor, ", n =", Ativos_por_setor, ", ", percent(fraction)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ymax = ymax, ymin = ymin, xmax = 4, xmin = 3, fill = Setor)) +
  geom_rect() +
  geom_text(aes(x = xlabel, y = ylabel, label = label)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = xlabel_repel, y = ylabel, label = label)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    labels = Quantidade_de_ativos_por_setor$Setor,
    values = getPalette(colorcount)
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  xlim(c(2, 4.5)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how can I push the labels to outside the chart, because I still think it's a little bit messy.

Comment: @MattiaValsangiacomo In the `mutate` get rid of `xlabel` and set `xlabel_repel = 4.5` Then, remove `geom_text`, keeping only `geom_text_repel`.